# How to optimize for loop with several conditions that depends on every step in iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, optimization

I have to write code that checks every point in the matrix 2000x2000 if it fulfills all given conditions. To speed up the iterations I put some calculations outside the loop. Is it any way to fasten this for loop or use another way to get the matrix A with value of 1 in places where all this conditions are satisfied ? I though about np.where function or creating matrix of True and False elements - but the conditions changes through iterations so it finally took longer.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros(2000, 2000)

(i, j) = A.shape
x = list(range(int(-0.5 * i), int(0.5 * i), 1))
y = list(range(int(-0.5 * j), int(0.5 * j), 1))
r = 50
w = 30
h = 150

w_tr = np.array([(-0.5 * w, 0.5 * h), (0.5 * w, 0.5 * h), (0.5 * w, -0.5 * h), (-0.5 * w, -0.5 * h)]).T


x_squared_A = list((np.array(x) - w_tr[0, 0]) ** 2)  # list (x-a)^2 for  A
y_squared_A = list((np.array(y) - w_tr[1, 0]) ** 2)  # list (y-b)^2 for  A
x_squared_B = list((np.array(x) - w_tr[0, 1]) ** 2)  # list (x-a)^2 for  B
y_squared_B = list((np.array(y) - w_tr[1, 1]) ** 2)  # list (y-b)^2 for  B
x_squared_C = list((np.array(x) - w_tr[0, 2]) ** 2)  # list (x-a)^2 for  C
y_squared_C = list((np.array(y) - w_tr[1, 2]) ** 2)  # list (y-b)^2 for  C
x_squared_D = list((np.array(x) - w_tr[0, 3]) ** 2)  # list (x-a)^2 for  D
y_squared_D = list((np.array(y) - w_tr[1, 3]) ** 2)  # list (y-b)^2 for  D
r_squared = r ** 2


for m in range(i):
    for vm in range(j):
        if (w_tr[1, 2] <= y[vm] < w_tr[1, 0] and w_tr[0, 0] - r <= x[m] < w_tr[0, 1] + r) or \
                (w_tr[1, 2] - r <= y[vm] < w_tr[1, 0] + r and w_tr[0, 0] <= x[m] < w_tr[0, 1]) or \
                x_squared_A[m] + y_squared_A[vm] < r_squared or \
                x_squared_B[m] + y_squared_B[vm] < r_squared or \
                x_squared_C[m] + y_squared_C[vm] < r_squared or \
                x_squared_D[m] + y_squared_D[vm] < r_squared:
            A[vm, m] = 1
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: I don't see anything you can do with the conditions, but you can try multithreading since every iteration can be run simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some redundant computations in your loop.  For instance, `w_tr[1, 2] - r` is a constant since `w_tr` is not modified in your loop if I'm not mistaken.  Therefore you can do this once.  Same for `w_tr[1, 2]` as computing this requires to access a dictionary.  So there are various simple optimisations you can perform like this by moving outside the loop some computations that do not depend on the for loop variable.

This gives the following code:

```py
w_tr12 = w_tr[1, 2]
w_tr12_minus_r = w_tr[1, 2] - r
w_tr00 = w_tr[0, 0]
w_tr00_minus_r = w_tr[0, 0] - r
w_tr01 = w_tr[0, 1]
w_tr01_plus_r = w_tr[0, 1] + r
w_tr10 = w_tr[1, 0]
w_tr10_plus_r = w_tr[1, 0] + r

for m in range(i):
    xm = x[m]
    x_squared_Am = x_squared_A[m]
    x_squared_Bm = x_squared_B[m]
    x_squared_Cm = x_squared_C[m]
    x_squared_Dm = x_squared_D[m]

    cond1 = w_tr00_minus_r <= xm < w_tr01_plus_r
    cond2 = w_tr00 <= xm < w_tr01
    for vm in range(j):
        if (cond1 and w_tr12 <= y[vm] < w_tr10) or \
           (cond2 and w_tr12_minus_r <= y[vm] < w_tr10_plus_r) or \
                x_squared_Am + y_squared_A[vm] < r_squared or \
                x_squared_Bm + y_squared_B[vm] < r_squared or \
                x_squared_Cm + y_squared_C[vm] < r_squared or \
                x_squared_Dm + y_squared_D[vm] < r_squared:
            A[vm, m] = 1
```

Not tremendous but I could go from `19.5` seconds to `8.5` on my machine.  If you want better optimisations, multithreading as proposed by @mike67 seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your hints, I wanted to add a comment to your answer, but there is some limitation of 500 signs so I am posting it as answer. I tried to use multiprocessing in the way that for loop would be run 6 times in the same time with singular condition like x_squared_Cm + y_squared_C[vm] < r_squared, then I will sum the resulting matrices of ones and zeros. I fastly writed some functions to try this method, but it seems that ProcessPoolExecutor returns iterables instead of np.arrays - then this code does not work as I am not able to sum the resulting matrices. Is there any method of converting resulting iterable to the numpy 2D array ? I tried np.array() function, but it reterned some empty array.

```
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np



def loop_1(i,j, r, A, x, y, w_tr, x_squared_A, x_squared_B, x_squared_C, x_squared_D, y_squared_A, y_squared_B, y_squared_C, y_squared_D, r_squared, max_r):
    A_1 = A
    for m in range(int(0.5 * i - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * i + max_r + 2)):
        for vm in range(int(0.5 * j - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * j + max_r + 2)):
            if w_tr[1, 2] <= y[vm] < w_tr[1, 0] and w_tr[0, 0]-r <= x[m] < w_tr[0, 1]+r:
                    A_1[vm, m] = 1
            else:
                continue
    return A_1

def loop_2(i,j, r, A, x, y, w_tr, x_squared_A, x_squared_B, x_squared_C, x_squared_D, y_squared_A, y_squared_B, y_squared_C, y_squared_D, r_squared, max_r):
    A_2 = A
    for m in range(int(0.5 * i - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * i + max_r + 2)):
        for vm in range(int(0.5 * j - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * j + max_r + 2)):
            if w_tr[1, 2]-r <= y[vm] < w_tr[1, 0]+r and w_tr[0, 0] <= x[m] < w_tr[0, 1]:
                    A_2[vm, m] = 1
            else:
                continue
    return A_2

def loop_3(i,j, r, A, x, y, w_tr, x_squared_A, x_squared_B, x_squared_C, x_squared_D, y_squared_A, y_squared_B, y_squared_C, y_squared_D, r_squared, max_r):
    A_3 = A
    for m in range(int(0.5 * i - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * i + max_r + 2)):
        for vm in range(int(0.5 * j - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * j + max_r + 2)):
            if  x_squared_A[m] + y_squared_A[vm] < r_squared:
                    A_3[vm, m] = 1
            else:
                continue
    return A_3

def loop_4(i,j, r, A, x, y, w_tr, x_squared_A, x_squared_B, x_squared_C, x_squared_D, y_squared_A, y_squared_B, y_squared_C, y_squared_D, r_squared, max_r):
    A_4 = A
    for m in range(int(0.5 * i - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * i + max_r + 2)):
        for vm in range(int(0.5 * j - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * j + max_r + 2)):
            if x_squared_B[m] + y_squared_B[vm] < r_squared:
                    A_4[vm, m] = 1
            else:
                continue
    return A_4

def loop_5(i,j, r, A, x, y, w_tr, x_squared_A, x_squared_B, x_squared_C, x_squared_D, y_squared_A, y_squared_B, y_squared_C, y_squared_D, r_squared, max_r):
    A_5 = A
    for m in range(int(0.5 * i - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * i + max_r + 2)):
        for vm in range(int(0.5 * j - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * j + max_r + 2)):
            if x_squared_C[m] + y_squared_C[vm] < r_squared:
                    A_5[vm, m] = 1
            else:
                continue
    return A_5

def loop_6(i,j, r, A, x, y, w_tr, x_squared_A, x_squared_B, x_squared_C, x_squared_D, y_squared_A, y_squared_B, y_squared_C, y_squared_D, r_squared, max_r):
    A_6 = A
    for m in range(int(0.5 * i - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * i + max_r + 2)):
        for vm in range(int(0.5 * j - max_r - 2), int(0.5 * j + max_r + 2)):
            if x_squared_D[m] + y_squared_D[vm] < r_squared:
                    A_6[vm, m] = 1
            else:
                continue
    return A_6 


def main():
    w = 30
    h = 150
    r = 50

    A = np.zeros((2000, 2000))  

    (i, j) = A.shape  # i,j współrzędne macierzy,  x,y  współrzędne układu
    x = list(range(int(-0.5 * i), int(0.5 * i), 1))
    y = list(range(int(-0.5 * j), int(0.5 * j), 1))

    wierzcholki = np.array([(-0.5 * w, 0.5 * h), (0.5 * w, 0.5 * h), (0.5 * w, -0.5 * h), (-0.5 * w, -0.5 * h)]).T
    w_tr = wierzcholki

    x_squared_A = list((np.array(x) - w_tr[0, 0]) ** 2)
    y_squared_A = list((np.array(y) - w_tr[1, 0]) ** 2)
    x_squared_B = list((np.array(x) - w_tr[0, 1]) ** 2)
    y_squared_B = list((np.array(y) - w_tr[1, 1]) ** 2)
    x_squared_C = list((np.array(x) - w_tr[0, 2]) ** 2)
    y_squared_C = list((np.array(y) - w_tr[1, 2]) ** 2)
    x_squared_D = list((np.array(x) - w_tr[0, 3]) ** 2)
    y_squared_D = list((np.array(y) - w_tr[1, 3]) ** 2)
    r_squared = r ** 2

    max_r = np.sqrt(
        (0.5 * w + r) ** 2 + (0.5 * h + r) ** 2)

    args = [i,j, r, A, x, y, w_tr, x_squared_A, x_squared_B, x_squared_C, x_squared_D, y_squared_A, y_squared_B,
            y_squared_C, y_squared_D, r_squared, max_r]

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [executor.map(loop_1, args),
                   executor.map(loop_2, args),
                   executor.map(loop_3, args),
                   executor.map(loop_4, args),
                   executor.map(loop_5, args),
                   executor.map(loop_6, args)]

    for result in results:
        A += result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```